# Undefined index: file_name in download pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter

download pdf file file database. it gives an error

```
$fileInfo = $this->User_Model->getRows($markid);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($fileInfo);
echo '</pre>';
$file='uploads/files/'.$fileInfo['file_name'];


     the output 

   Array
    (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 0
        [regno] => 01107402042
        [appno] => 10001
        [certid] => 4
        [file_name] => 
      81368151bdef9689d696d0e942c64293.pdf
        [status] => Uploaded
        [update_date] => 2018-09-14
     )

      )
```

it gives an error.A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: file_name

how to solve this error?.

Answer (score 0):

pass `$fileinfo[0][file_name]` as file_name is under the 0th coloumn

Comment: thanks for your answer. i want to display in modal window. how?

Comment: thats a long procedure, check how to open modal using javascript and display data using php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `base_url()`, so you need to load URL helper in autoload file `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

You can load manually in controller or in view  `$this->load->helper('url')`;

Now `base_url()` is available anywhere in controller or view.

```
$file= base_url().'uploads/files/'.$fileInfo[0]['file_name'];
```

Note: As you print array data. The resultant data is an array or array. 
So filename is at `[0]['file_name']`.